# WCF changing from Message to Transport security

Tags: web-services, wcf, security, soapui, wcf-security

Currently our services use Message level security, but as we are using Soap UI for testing. After many hours, we discovered that Soap UI is not good with Message level security, something to do with java core I believe.

Have tried to unravel the web.config to use Transport level security, which I believe is supported by Soap UI, but as soon as I change the security mode to Transport I get the following error:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

Can someone have a look at the config as I am sure that I have missed something.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService" 
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="ServiceWsHttpBinding" 
              name="ClaimServiceHttpEndpoint" 
              contract="IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceWsHttpBinding" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                 negotiateServiceCredential="false" 
                 establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientEndpointBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>        
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=test.service.com" 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                            storeName="My" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyObject.UserAuthentication,  MyObject.Utils" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="MyObject.Utils.AuthPolicy, Myobject.Utils" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />        
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Your configuration file has `<security mode="Message">`.  Post client and service config files where you've attempted Transport security.

Comment: Just change security mode to Transport